# Efficient way to conditionally add items to HashMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, optimization, java-9

Is there an efficient and least redundant way to conditionally put new items in map.

```
GenericObject genericObject;
...
FieldObject obj = genericObject.getFieldObject();
if(obj == null) {
    map.put("key1", null);
    map.put("key2", null);
} else {
    map.put("key1", obj.getField1());
    map.put("key2", obj.getField2());
}
```

The best I can do is the following, but was curious if there was a better way to do the above in Java 9.

```
boolean insert = obj != null;
map.put("key1", insert? obj.getField1() : null);
map.put("key2", insert? obj.getField2() : null);
```

Comment: why do you need to put nulls there? is it to override those keys?

Comment: Yeah. Those values will likely be overridden.

Comment: Choose 1 either efficient or least redundant

Comment: @ManchuRatt your code is fine, I would `.remove` instead of setting nulls though

Comment: @ManchuRatt Are you using a `Map<String, Object>`? That's one problem to start off with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Optional`s:

```
Optional<FieldObject> obj = Optional.ofNullable(genericObject.getFieldObject());
map.put("key1", obj.map(FieldObject::getField1).orElse(null));
map.put("key2", obj.map(FieldObject::getField2).orElse(null));
```

Comment: "wrap it in Optional, and then unwrap it to null" - doesn't sound good to me

Comment: @snr That doesn't mean he did a mistake. It just doesn't sound good to Andrew Tobilko. But answer is still correct

Comment: I guess I'll benchmark performance and see if performance hit is significant.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko agreed. that might functionally work, but its a really poor choice to make. For one, the overhead with `Optional` wrapping and another majpr with the `null` values in a `Map`.

Comment: @ManchuRatt Is this kind of optimalisation really needed? Even if it's better or worse, we are talking about nanoseconds here.

Comment: There are different metrics of efficiency. It’s a waste of memory to put `null` values into a map, when `remove` would do as well. So `FieldObject obj = genericObject.getFieldObject(); if(obj == null) { map.remove("key1"); map.put("key2"); } else { map.put("key1", obj.getField1()); map.put("key2", obj.getField2()); }` does not waste memory and puts less constraints to the actual `Map` implementation, e.g. would also work with a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: While your answer is perfectly correct, it's surely nothing I'd recommend. Unlike Holger's comment, it doesn't solve any real problem; it just makes the code "more modern".

Answer (score 0):

You could delegate the check for null to the `GenericObject` by adding these 2 methods to it:

```
public String getField1() {
    return fieldObject == null ? null : fieldObject.getField1();
}

public String getField2() {
    return fieldObject == null ? null : fieldObject.getField2();
}
```

Then

```
map.put("key1", genericObject.getField1());
map.put("key2", genericObject.getField2());
```

Answer (score 0):

Put null as a value to a map it's quite weird.

```
map.put("key", null);
map.get("key"); // -- is it null because no such key or because the value is null?
```

So, is it no necessary to add nulls you just can use optional

```
Optional.ofNullable(obj).ifPresent(v -> {
   map.put("key1", obj.getField1());
   map.put("key2", obj.getField2());
});
```

But your plain `if`-statement is more readable